# How to create a readonly text using html helper in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to disable a textbox in the view. So I use following code:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", Model.ID, new { readonly="true" })%>
```

or

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", Model.ID, new { enable="false" })%>
```

Both of them don't work.  what's the solution?

Comment: Maybe you could output the text to a DIV if it's only meant to be read?

Comment: In addition to using the overloaded method, you should also probably use disabled="disabled" - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: > [Here is n You can see. how to create read only textbox in MVC](http://www.codeshower.blogspot.in/2012/09/mvc-how-to-create-readonly-textbox-in.html)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", Model.ID, new { @readonly="readonly" })%>
```

I'm not sure you have to use the overload with 4 parameters. You should be able to use the one with 3, but you need to append @ to the readonly since readonly is a keyword in C#. And setting @readonly to readonly is XHTML compliant.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", Model.ID, null, new { @readonly="true" })%>
```

instead of

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", Model.ID, new { @readonly="true" })%>
```

If you check [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492984.aspx), you can see that the third parameter is not `htmlAttributes`, as you probably expected.

You need to use the [overload with four parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049.aspx).

Comment: It seems like this has changed and that the 3rd parameter *IS* htmlAttributes.

Answer (score 6):

Taking advantage of the more up to date API you can use:

Web Forms Engine:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

Razor Engine:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind a [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) TextBox will not be submitted with a html form, but a [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) TextBox will.

MVC3 [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) shows the signature as Html.TextBox(string name, object value, object htmlAttributes) used above.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not forced to show a readonly textbox in your web page, consider using the `@Html.DisplayFor`  helper: your output will be readonly (actually it will be just a text in a div) and will be part of the Model when the engine will model bind on submit.

Comment: Not sure why but this, *"be part of the Model when the engine will model bind on submit."* ,does not work, for me, on MVC 5. For an `int`, for instance, I always get a `0`.  If I use this --> `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID, new { @readonly = "readonly" })` it works as expected.  I did not DownVote since I can't verify that I'm not the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Or this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", Model.ID, new { @disabled="true" })%>
```