# MVC 3 html.TextBoxFor readonly Properties to be set dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.textbox

```
    <div class="editor-label" style="position:static">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Date, "Date")%>
        <span style="padding-left:52px">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Date)%>
```

Here i want to set the readonly property to the textbox on a button click/Action Click. how do i do it.
At the initial page the data is been displayed as readonly and on the edit button click. This should be changed to editable textbox.I have almost seven textboxes i need to do the same for all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this can be accomplished with a little javascript. Here's a simple example.

Render each textbox as readonly on page load:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

Add a click handler for your edit button that will remove the readonly attribute from each textbox:

```
$("#editButton").click(function() {
    $("#Date").removeAttr("readonly");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it doesn't work.I tried a lot with other options but javascript doesn't work at all with the MVC controls. $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#datebox").attr('@readonly',' readonly');
});
 <div class="editor-label" style="position:static">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Date, "Date")%>
            <span style="padding-left:52px">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Date, new { @class = "textboxes",@id = "datebox")%>
                
              
            </span>
        </div>

Comment: Change your javascript call to this: $("#datebox").attr('readonly',' readonly'); Also, in your Date textbox, you don't need to use @id, it can just be id. Leave @class as it is. The '@' is for using C# reserved words as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
 Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Whatever, new {id = "", @class="", 
      placeholder="" @readonly="readonly"})
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put

```
@readonly = true
```

or

```
@readonly = *your-expression-here*
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153912/how-to-creat-a-readonly-text-using-html-helper-in-asp-net-mvc